# proof: subgroup normal subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group with finite elements and $U \subset G$ a subgroup of $G$ with $|U| = m \in \Bbb{N}_{>0}$. Show that: If $U$ is the only subgroup of $G$ with $m$ elements, then $U$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

My idea was, to make a proof by contradiction, , but i didn't gone very far..

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If $H$ is a subgroup, show that a conjugate subgroup (subgroups of the form $gHg^{-1}$) must have the same number of elements. In your case, this means $gUg^{-1}=U$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: So $|gUg^{-1}|=m=|U|$ because they have the same number of elements. And because there has to be only one subgroup with $m$ elements, then one has $gUg^{-1}=U$ and that is just the definition of a normal subgroup?

Comment: $U$ is even *characteristic* subgroup, that is, for any $\psi \in Aut(G)$, $\psi(U)=U$.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein: if $U$ is a subgroup of $G$ with a unique index$[G:U]$, then $U \unlhd G$.